# Getting wrong result when using Compound multiplication statement - C#

Tags: c#, multiplication, compound-assignment

I noticed something very strange. In the code snippet below, the result outputted on the Console is always `0`

```
int result = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
  result *= 10 + i;
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

It looks like `result *= 10 + i;` always multiplies `10` to the `result` (where `result` is `0`) and does not add `i` to it.

If I change just the multiplication line...

```
int result = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
  result = result * 10 + i;
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This outputs the correct `result` on the Console - that is `123`.

My question is, why is `result *= 10 + i;` not working correctly - and always giving the `result` as `0`?

Comment: To make it more clear, its `result *= (10+i);`.

Comment: The first one does:  `10 + i` and then multiplies it by `0`, and so it's always 0.  The second one takes `(0 * 10) + i` and so it increases with each loop iteration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of the order of operations.

```
result = result * 10 + i
```

is equivalent to...

```
result = (result * 10) + i
```

...but...

```
result *= 10 + i
```

is the same as...

```
result = result * (10 + i)
```

Comment: And the compound version of `result = result * 10 + i;` is `result *= 10; result += i;` or even `(result *= 10) += i;`